# C++ Resize Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I've been trying to resize this array, and it compiles just fine, but when I run it I get this really long error message.

Here's the code for the function:

```
void arrayClass_Namespace::arrayClass::resize(int newSize)
{
    std::cout << "\nPlease input a new size for the array: ";
    std::cin >> newSize;

    assert(newSize < MAX_SIZE);

    int *resize_arr = new int[newSize];
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        resize_arr[index] = arr[index];
    }

    size++;
    arr = resize_arr;
    delete[] resize_arr;
}
```

Here's the updated code that works perfectly fine now:

```
void arrayTools_GabriellaRamirez::arrayTools::resize(int newSize)
{
    std::cout << "\nPlease input a new size for the array: ";
    std::cin >> newSize;

    assert(newSize < MAX_SIZE);

    int *resize_arr = new int[newSize];
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        resize_arr[index] = arr[index];
    }

    for(int index = size; size < newSize; index++)
    {
        size++;
    }

    for(int index = size; size > newSize; index++)
    {
        size--;
    }

    delete [] arr;
    arr = resize_arr;
}
```

Comment: These sorts of problems just go away if you use `std::vector<int> arr` instead of `int* arr`.

Comment: In the future please post the error message. "really long error message" doesn't help future visitors whatsoever.

Comment: @Robᵩ `std::cout << "\nPlease input a new size for the array: ";` I don't think he's needing production code here, just practice.

Comment: @remyabel Sorry about that, I didn't really understand the error message. The beginning started with backtrace, then it had all of these characters and it aborted with a core dump.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yeah, if I could I would use a vector, but I'm mainly just practicing with arrays.

Comment: @user3062299 Asking for the `newSze` value inside the function via `cin` instead of just using the parameter value looks **blatantly wrong** for me!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was just using that to make sure it was actually running when I ran the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete[] resize_arr` is deleting the new array you made. You need to do

```
delete[] arr;
arr = resize_arr;
```

As an aside, you don't check to make sure the new array size is not smaller than `used` so you could potentially write out of bounds of the new array.

Also I think `size++` is not correct.